# Recursive method not working. Need ; ?

Tags: scala

Trying to create a recursive function that prints the highest element of an array.

It's saying it needs a `;` before `else maxi=xs.head` and a `}` after `max(xs.tail)`

I didn't think scala uses semi colons, when should you use them and what are some other basic syntactical rules.

```
var maxi = 0 
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {if (xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException() 
      else if (xs.tail.isEmpty) maxi
      else if (xs.tail.head > xs.head) maxi = xs.tail.head
      max(xs.tail)
      else maxi=xs.head
      max(xs.tail)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala uses semicolons, but they're optional at the end of a line. That is if a semicolon would be legal at the end of a line (i.e. the line doesn't end in the middle of an expression (like `a +`)), one is automatically inserted.

That said, despite the error message your problem doesn't actually have anything to do with semicolons. Your problem is that you need braces if you want to have more than expression in an if- or else-block.

PS: Note that using a mutable non-local variable to keep track of your state is a bad idea design-wise and will give you trouble if you call your method more than once (without resetting the variable in between).

PPS: You should closely look at what you do when `xs.tail` is empty. Are you sure that logic is correct?

Answer (score 9):

This looks like homework, I'm basing this only on the fact that this is part of the first homework assignment in Odersky's online Coursera course.

If it's not, let me know, but I'll assume it is, so I'll just give a hint.. look at how your if/else branch is organized.

The first week videos in the course cover the semicolon inference of Scala.

Answer (score 6):

Some proper formatting will show you the problem:

```
var maxi = 0 
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) 
    throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException() 
  else if(xs.tail.isEmpty) 
    maxi
  else if(xs.tail.head > xs.head) { // <-- need this opening brace
    maxi = xs.tail.head             // because there are two lines 
    max(xs.tail)                    // in the body of the if-statement
  }                                 // <-- and this closing brace
  else {
    maxi=xs.head
    max(xs.tail)
  }
}
```

Semi-colons are valid in Scala code, but they not required to the degree that they are in Java.  In other words, you can write code that doesn't need them, or you can use them for certain things if you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Coursera 'Functional Programming With Scala' example homework. You have course forum for this kind of questions.

You should digg deeper into recursion and solve this task without any additional var's. There is a hint in Lists source about helper function. Use it.

Comment: I agree with no use of mutable global state (`maxi`) as implicitly specified in the exercise when it says in the hint "You might need to define an auxiliary method".

Answer (score 1):

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def loop(a: Int, b: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (b.tail.isEmpty)
      if (a >= b.head) a
      else b.head
    else 
      if (a >= b.head) loop(a, b.tail)
      else loop(b.head, b.tail)
  }
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()
  else loop(xs.head, xs.tail)  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def maxNew(xs: List[Int], maxx: Int): Int ={
   if(xs.isEmpty) maxx else { 
     if (maxx<=xs.head) 
      maxNew(xs.tail, xs.head)
    else 
      maxNew(xs.tail, maxx)
   }
 }

  if(xs.isEmpty) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException()
  else maxNew(xs,0)        
}
```

Comment: be easy and use a recursive.